# ¿Qué relación tiene el MsBuild con los compiladores vbc.exe y csc.exe de Visual Basic y C# respectivamente?

Tags: c#, vb.net, .net

Estos son los conceptos que acabo de leer en internet:

VBC.EXE es el compilador de visual basic.
CSC.EXE es el compilador de C#

MsBuild es el compilador que usa Visual Studio para traducir visual basic y c# a codigo intermedio.

---

No entiendo como se relacionan estos conceptos?

Comment: la pregunta es, que hace cada compilador?

Comment: como MsBuild es un concepto nuevo para mi, quería saber que relación guarda con los conocidos vbc.exe y csc.exe.

Answer (score 1):

`MsBuild` es una aplicación que te permite construir una solución completa. Utiliza el compilador necesario (csc o vbc) para compilar los archivos. Si quieres verlo asi, MsBuild es una aplicacion de mas alto nivel que los compiladores de lenguajes.

Cuando tu compilas una solución desde Visual Studio, este utiliza MsBuild para ir compilando uno a uno todos los archivos de la solucion, añadiendo la ruta a ellos, sus referencias etc... Para compilar cada archivo individual, MsBuild llama a csc o vbc según corresponda.

Comment: entonces MsBuild cumple la función de Task Runner, ejecutando tareas de compilación.